# Execute multiple php scripts with multiple callbacks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Actually i have 10 php scripts (getlatest_t_s2.php, getlatest_h_s3.php...) and execute them in 10 separate javascripts and get an id from the callback function. Let's see what i mean.

HTML

```
<td>Temperature</td>
<td align="right"><div id="last_temp_s2"></div></td>
```

JS

```
var scriptToExecute="getlatest_t_s2.php";//php script

//any data that you might want to send to the php script.
var data ='anyData';

//call ajax function
makeAjaxRequest(scriptToExecute,data,callBack);
function callBack(data){
    $('#last_temp_s2').html(data);
}

function makeAjaxRequest(url,data,_callBack,_failure){
    $.ajax({
        url: '../php/',
        datatype:"php",
        type:'get',
        data: data,
        success:function(data){
            _callBack(data);
        },
        error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            if(!_failure){
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
            else
            {
                _failure(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So my question is, instead of executing 10 different javascripts for each php-script, is it possible to just execute one javascript or at least less than 10?

Comment: Does your current code working? Anyway, you have to make 10 different calls, you can reduce the code for that, but on the background each script should be called, so it's all the same.

Comment: Yes, it is working. Oh, okay - i thought there is an easier way to do that.

Comment: Can't you create one PHP file that returns all your data in JSON format and then parse it in JavaScript? This way you could decrease the number of requests to just one.

Comment: You can iterate through some prefixes to build the filenames and pass them by a loop to your sendRequest function, it will spare you lines of code, but it still will call the function 10 times

Comment: Guilherme Sehn - that totally makes sense. Why didn't i think of that?! I guess that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd suggest is to create one well-structured PHP file in which, you would process all the data into an array, then send that array (`json encode($array)`) to your JS, which could then handle all the JSON.

The fact that you'd send 10 request to possibly 10 line files creates alot of serverload if alot of people are visiting your website, thus one file will greatly optimize your website loading speed, this is good for SEO as well as your visitors, who won't have to wait 1, possible 2 seconds for the response from the server.

Modern browsers all have native methods to parse JSON, so does jQuery so you should be fine on processing the JSON data via JS by any means.

**Credits** Guilherme Sehn already pointed this out to make it clear.